# Indexing for each word in the TextFile Content Using Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to index each word in a text file Using java

Index means i am denoting indexing of words here..

This is my sample file https://pastebin.com/hxB8t56p
(the actual file I want to index is much larger)

This is the code I have tried so far

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> sen = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> fin = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:\\folder\\poem.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String[] split = content.split("\\s"); // Split text file content
for(String b:split) {
    ar.add(b); // added into the ar arraylist //ar contains every line of poem
}
FileInputStream fstream = null;
String answer = "";fstream=new FileInputStream("D:\\folder\\poemt.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
int count = 1;
int songnum = 0;

while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null) {
    String text = strLine.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""); // Replace numbers from txt
    String nums = strLine.split("(?=\\D)")[0]; // get digits from strLine
    if (nums.matches(".*[0-9].*")) {
        songnum = Integer.parseInt(nums); // Parse string to int
    }
    String regex = ".*\\d+.*";
    boolean result = strLine.matches(regex);
    if (result == true) { // check if strLine contain digit
        count = 1;
    }
    answer = songnum + "." + count + "(" + text + ")";
    count++;
    sen.add(answer); // added songnum + line number and text to sen
}

for(int i = 0;i<sen.size();i++) { // loop to match and get word+poem number+line number
    for (int j = 0; j < ar.size(); j++) {
        if (sen.get(i).contains(ar.get(j))) {
            if (!ar.get(j).isEmpty()) {
                String x = ar.get(j) + " - " + sen.get(i);
                x = x.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", ""); // replace single line sentence
                String[] sp = x.split("\\s+");
                word.add(sp[0]); // each word in the poem is added to the word arraylist
                fin.add(x); // word+poem number+line number
            }
        }
    }
}
Set<String> listWithoutDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<String>(fin); // Remove duplicates
fin.clear();fin.addAll(listWithoutDuplicates);
Locale lithuanian = new Locale("ta");
Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(lithuanian); // sort array
Collections.sort(fin,lithuanianCollator);
System.out.println(fin);   


    (change in blossom. - 0.2,1.2, &  the - 0.1,1.2, & then - 0.1,1.2)
```

Comment: It is difficult to read your code. Please reformat it.
The test case really helps, though.

Comment: This question will likely need more upvotes to gather enough attention.

Comment: Please elaborate on the word **index**. The test case shows that the words "And" , "more" are not considered. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Comment: @Pal Laden actually there is no space between 0. and And which i used to split words .my original file has space .that was my mistake i forgot to leave space there:(

Comment: @Eldar i dont want to just read a text file i want to create indexfor each word in text file

Comment: @Pal Laden i have corrected my pastbin thank you.

Comment: Well, then you can just read a file and use `.split(" ")` to turn it into an array. Then, instead of using (for unknown reason) four entire ArrayLists and an array, you can actually write efficient code.

Comment: yaa.i used "\\s+" to split here.Please See my Pastbin i have attached my output there

Comment: I believe `split("\\b")` is more appropriate for splitting the string into words. For example it will give you the word `blossom` and not `blossom.` (with the trailing period)

Comment: @Abra thank you for that.i will replace in my code

Comment: @Abra. note that the "expected output" includes trailing punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first copy the intended output for your pasted example, and then go over the code to find how to change it:

> Poem.txt

```
0.And then the day came,
  to remain blossom.
1.more painful
  then the blossom.
```

> Expected output

```
[blossom. - 0.2,1.2, came, - 0.1, day - 0.1, painful - 1.1, remain - 0.2, the - 0.1,1.2, then - 0.1,1.2, to - 0.2]
```

As @Pal Laden notes in comments, some words (`the`, `and`) are not being indexed. It  is probable that [stopwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) are being ignored for indexing purposes.

Current output of code is

```
[blossom. - 0.2, blossom. - 1.2, came, - 0.1, day - 0.1, painful - 1.1, remain - 0.2, the - 0.1, the - 1.2, then - 0.1, then - 1.2, to - 0.2]
```

So, assuming you fix your stopwords, you are actually quite close. Your `fin` array contains `word+poem number+line number`, but it should contain `word+*list* of poem number+line number`. There are several ways to fix this. First, we will need to do stopword removal:

```
// build stopword-removal set "toIgnore"
String[] stopWords = new String[]{ "a", "the", "of", "more", /*others*/ };
Set<String> toIgnore = new HashSet<>();
for (String s: stopWords) toIgnore.add(s);

if ( ! toIgnore.contains(sp[0)) fin.add(x); // only process non-ignored words
// was: fin.add(x);
```

Now, lets fix the list problem. The easiest (but ugly) way is to fix "fin" at the very end:

```
List<String> fixed = new ArrayList<>();
String prevWord = "";
String prevLocs = "";
for (String s : fin) {
    String[] parts = s.split(" - ");
    if (parts[0].equals(prevWord)) {
        prevLocs += "," + parts[1];
    } else {
        if (! prevWord.isEmpty()) fixed.add(prevWord + " - " + prevLocs);
        prevWord = parts[0];
        prevLocs = parts[1];
    }
}
// last iteration
if (! prevWord.isEmpty()) fixed.add(prevWord + " - " + prevLocs);

System.out.println(fixed);
```

**How to do it the right way (TM)**

You code can be much improved. In particular, using flat `ArrayList`s for everything is not always the best idea. Maps are great for building indices:

```
// build stopwords
String[] stopWords = new String[]{ "and", "a", "the", "to", "of", "more", /*others*/ };
Set<String> toIgnore = new HashSet<>();
for (String s: stopWords) toIgnore.add(s);

// prepare always-sorted, quick-lookup set of terms
Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ta"));
Map<String, List<String>> terms = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> lithuanianCollator.compare(o1, o2));

// read lines; if line starts with number, store separately
Pattern countPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)\\.(.*)");
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/poem.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int poemCount = 0;
int lineCount = 1;
for (String line: content.split("[\n\r]+")) {
    line = line.toLowerCase().trim(); // remove spaces on both sides

    // update locations
    Matcher m = countPattern.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        poemCount = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        lineCount = 1;
        line = m.group(2); // ignore number for word-finding purposes
    } else {
        lineCount ++;
    }

    // read words in line, with locations already taken care of
    for (String word: line.split(" ")) {
        if ( ! toIgnore.contains(word)) {
            if ( ! terms.containsKey(word)) {
                terms.put(word, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            terms.get(word).add(poemCount + "." + lineCount);
        }
    }
}

// output formatting to match that of your code
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e: terms.entrySet()) {
    output.add(e.getKey() + " - " + String.join(",", e.getValue()));
}
System.out.println(output);
```

Which gives me `[blossom. - 0.2,1.2, came, - 0.1, day - 0.1, painful - 1.1, remain - 0.2, to - 0.2]`. I have not fixed the list of stopwords to get a perfect match, but that should be easy to do.